# Validation Application Block with ASP.NET MVC4 applications

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enterprise-library

I want to use the Enterprise Library Validation Application Block with my ASP.NET MVC4 application. Which version of Enterprise Library is recommended?
Can anyone provide an example of XML Configuration file for VAB for ASP.NET MVC4?

I found an example to work with ASP.NET on the MSDN website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664564(v=pandp.50).aspx
Will it also work with MVC4 application?

Answer (score 0):

VAB Attributes are DataAnnotations so they can be used with with MVC. Or if you want to use VAB as a validation engine then you could create a ModelValidatorProvider for Enterprise Library. 
SOURCE : [Entlib Official Site Discussion Forum](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/442768)